# How to save the data as a string from a csv file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts, jquery-csv

I'm making a local html5 stats page using Highcharts, and I want to get the data for my charts from a csv file allocated in my own laptop. The javascript code is:

```
 var arch = new FileReader();
 var content = arch.readAsArrayBuffer('./csvs/sample1.csv');
 //var content = arch.readAsText('./csvs/sample1.csv'.files);
 var sample = $.csv.toArrays(content);
 console.log(sample1);
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            min: -0.5,
            max: 5.5
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Scatter plot with regression line'
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Regression Line',
            data: [[0, 1.11], [5, 4.51]],
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 0
                }
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }, {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Observations',
            data: sample,
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

I'm using jquery-csv plugin too, but it doesn't work. I've tested with fopen but nothing too. The console tells me:

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.**

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what don't you understand about that error message? It expects a Blob (file contents), not a string.

Comment: Sorry, but Blob is an incomprenhensive word (term) for me, I'm spanish

Comment: Blob It's Binary Large OBject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read local file you need input type file:

```js
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
        var contents = e.target.result;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = contents;
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileinput"/>
<textarea id="output" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file into an object, then pass that object to your `FileReader.readAsXXX` method.

`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()` doesn't take a string.

[Here](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader) is some API docs for you that may help.

Answer (score 0):

`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(..)` expects a Blob as parameter, not a string. A blob is binary data, read from a file. You can find the documentation about FileReader on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer).

It tells us that we can pass a `File` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)) instead too, which we can extract from a `FileList` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)).

You cannot read files directly from your computer. That would be a major security breach. What we need to do is have an input element where we either select the file, or where we drag-and-drop the file onto. Then we read the file and execute your code:

```
<input type="file" id="myfile"> <input type="button" id="csvbutton" value="Load">
```

And javascript:

```
$("#csvbutton").on( "click", function() {
  var file = $("#myfile")[0].files[0];
  if( file == undefined ) {
    //RIP
    return;
  }
  var arch = new FileReader();
  var content = arch.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  //etc
} );
```